# comunicacion entre Visual Studio C # y un PLC

Tags: c#

Necesito hacer un sistema en Visual Studio (C #) que me permita comunicarme con el PLC , pero por el momento no puedo encontrar una alternativa para obtener esta comunicación.
Estube leyendo la cominicacion MODBUS TCP/IP, no logro entender.

Como enviaria la informacion a un registro espesifico del PLC desde C# y como identificar ese Registro?

Agradecería si alguien pudiera guiarme en el tema.

Saludos.

Comment: Te refieres a ¿PLC o PCL?

Comment: es, control logico Programable (PLC)

Comment: Revisa esto: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3302450/plc-programing-in-c-sharp-net

Comment: Eh observado estos comentario me gustaría comunicarme con Brian Gideon que me habla de OPC.
Quiera saber cómo utilizaría esa comunicación. 
Se Podria?

Comment: Envíale un mensaje por Linkedin. https://stackoverflow.com/users/158779/brian-gideon